# How to combine two animateTransformation not silmutaneously but consecutively?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

I have the following transformations

```html
<svg height="205" width="365" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ --> <g>
<title></title>
<rect fill="none" height="207" id="canvas_background" width="367" x="-1" y="-1"></rect> </g> <g>
<title></title>
<g id="svg_3"> <path class="hinh1" d="m22,88.5a67.5,67.5 0 0 1 135,0l-135,0z" fill="none" id="svg_1" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" style="fill: rgb(92, 188, 214);stroke-linejoin: round;/* x: 100; *//* y: 100px; */"></path> <g transform="translate(-132.281 0)"><path class="hinh2" d="m207.0027,88.5a67.5,67.5 0 0 1 135,0l-135,0z" fill="none" id="svg_2" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" transform="rotate(180 274.503 54.7665) translate(0 70.8138) translate(0 -82.7702)" style="fill: rgb(214, 92, 188); stroke-linejoin: round;">
</path> 
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 0" to="0 56" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" id="one">
</animateTransform>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 0" to="-185 0" begin="one.end" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
</animateTransform>
</g> </g> </g> </svg>
```

I want the right semicircle to go down THEN go left (**not simultaneously**) to snap to the left semicircle.

I found that, the following code does not work as I expect, only the second one is triggered. Isn't it the case that `one.end` has no meaning here?

```
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 0" to="0 56" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" id="one">
</animateTransform>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 0" to="-185 0" begin="one.end" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
</animateTransform>
```

In addition, at the end of the animations, I want the right to stop for about 3s before repeating, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `to` and `for` attributes you can animate between several values by using the `values` attribute where the values for the transformation are separates by semicolons:

```html
<svg height="205" width="365" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect fill="none" height="207" id="canvas_background" width="367" x="-1" y="-1"></rect>
  </g>

  <g id="svg_3">
    <path class="hinh1" d="m22,88.5a67.5,67.5 0 0 1 135,0l-135,0z" fill="none" id="svg_1" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" style="fill: rgb(92, 188, 214);stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
    <g>
      <path class="hinh2" d="m207.0027,88.5a67.5,67.5 0 0 1 135,0l-135,0z" fill="none" id="svg_2" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" transform="rotate(180 274.503 54.7665) translate(0 70.8138) translate(0 -82.7702)" style="fill: rgb(214, 92, 188); stroke-linejoin: round;">
      </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" values="0 0;0 56;-185,56" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" id="one">
      </animateTransform>

    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```